# jquery - catch load of a specified element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to catch/handle the loads (also if it is dynamically loaded) of a specified items.

if the event is `click` it works fine:

```
$('#articles').on("click",".article",function(eo){
        //...               
    });
```

this is what i have tried:

```
$(document).on("load","input",function(){
    alert(1);
});​
```

this is how I'would use it:

```
<input type=hidden name='size' value=1>
<select name='size'>
  <option value=0>A4</option>
  <option value=1>A3</option><!--this will be selected, that is indicated with the hidden input-->
</select>
```

the script for do this:

```
$(document).on("load","input",function(e){
    var name = e.attr("name");
    var val = e.val(); 
    if(name!=""&& typeof(e)!="undefined")
    {
       e.parent().find('select[name='+name+']').val(val);               
    }       
});​
```

---

I'm asking some kind of on() function if it possible, because the manual says that it is preferred.

Comment: what do you want to do by expecting a `load` event on an `input`...are you sure what you are doing? by the way, what _are_ you doing?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the following:

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', 'input', function(e) {
    console.log($(this));
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YuKxd/).

If you're concerned about the experience of those using browsers that don't implement `DomNodeInserted`, then you can, of course, trigger an event with a custom event-name at the point at which the element is appended to the DOM, and then listen for *that* event with the `on()` method:

```
$(document).on('customEventName', 'input', function(e) {
    console.log($(this));
});

$('#add').click(
    function() {
        var i = $('input').length,
            input = $('<input />',{'id' : 'input_' + i});
        input.appendTo('body').trigger('customEventName');
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YuKxd/1/).

---

References:

- [DOM level 3 events, including `DOMNodeInserted`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the livequery plugin for jquery:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery

```
$('input') 
.livequery(function(){ 
alert(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is on dynamically loaded elements try `.live()`, which works like `.bind()` only keeps the search open for dynamically added elements and binds them when they appear.

Comment: `on()` replaced `live()` in jQuery 7.1+, `live()` is now deprecated (and should *not* be used). In jQuery 7 and below the documentation on the [`live() API entry`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) advises users to use [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) in preference to `live()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for specific elements, you can use `setTimeout` to periodically look for elements matching a selector that are new.

```
function findNew() {
   var $selected = $('.some-selector').filter(function() {
       return !$(this).data('filtered');
   });

   $(document).trigger({type: 'elementadded', elements:$selected });

   $selected.data('filtered', true);

   setTimeout(findNew, 500);
}

$(document).on('elementadded', function(e) {
  alert('found ' + e.elements.length + ' new elements.');
});

findNew();
```